# mobile.ajaxEnabled = false stop all ajax calls from working?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

Let's say I this  `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;` set for a page navigation for when a page is shown.

Would this stop all ajax calls from working? Say if I had a button that was an ajax call when pressed. When `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;` would that then force all ajax calls to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it will not force all ajax call to stop. It is just used on pageload only